# Можно ли найти определенные координаты у ImageView

Tags: java, android, imageview

У меня есть рамка , которая представляет из себя imageview , мне нужно найти нижний левый (x,y) и верхний правый (x,y)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, чтобы найти экранные координаты любого `View`, включая `ImageView`, надо сделать так:

```
int[] location = new int[2];
imageView.getLocationOnScreen(location);
//координаты левого верхнего угла относительно экрана
int x = location[0]; 
int y = location[1];
```

Comment: А вопрос был немного в другом =)

Comment: Надеюсь ТС догадается и сам, что координаты левого нижнего угла это будет `y+height`, а правого верхнего `x+width` :) - или это тоже надо разжевывать?